# Selenium error while running a loop

Tags: java, loops, selenium

I run a loop in my Selenium, and get an error while executing it

```
int count=FilterByOption.size();
    System.out.println(count);
    for (int i = 1; i < count; i++) {
        FilterByOption.get(1).click();
        System.out.println("Group by filter Selected");
```

and the error is:

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1

Comment: Start the loop from 0 `for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {`

Comment: Well, there obiously is no FilterByOption with the index 1 which you are trying to access. But another question would be: Why are you using a loop with an index if you are not using the index inside the loop at all and instead hard coded the value `FilterByOption.get(1)` into it?

Comment: means that you are trying to access the first element while there are no elements in the list.

Answer (score 2):

Your for loop is starting at 1 which would be the second index of FilterByOption. It should start at 0.

Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
```

Also, this line `FilterByOption.get(1).click();` will always get the second index of FilterByOption, I'm guessing you want to replace `.get(1)` with `.get(i)`. If there is only one item in FilterByOption and you call `FilterByOption.get(1)` you will get an IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score 0):

As the error you are seeing is :

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
```

It essentially means there is no value at `FilterByOption[1]` and the possible reason is the `List`, **`FilterByOption[]`** contains only single element which can be referenced by **`FilterByOption[0]`**. So you can modify the code block and start iterating the `List` as follows :

```
int count=FilterByOption.size();
System.out.println(count);
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) 
{
    FilterByOption.get(i).click();
    System.out.println("Group by filter Selected");
}
```